# How can I render text in a custom Cocoa NSView view with non-uniform scaling?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, text, drawing

I'm rendering a chart in a subclass of NSView; I've set the bounds of the custom view to reflect the boundaries of the chart in real-world units (i.e., seconds on the horizontal axis, feet on the vertical axis.

Now I want to annotate the chart with text, using NSString's drawAtPoint:withAttributes:. I can set the font size using my real-world units to get an appropriate text height in the view, but the text is (of course) squashed horizontally.

What's the best way to render the text with normal scaling? I'm considering:

- Rendering the text in a separate overlay view (either a sub-view or super-view of the chart) that uses "normal" scaling?
- Can I manipulate the font metrics to compensate for the scaling?
- Or should I revert to normal scaling in my view, and handle the scaling in my rendering?

I'm going to continue experimenting with each of these, but I'm hoping someone will save me some time here...

Thanks in advance!